# Como subir archivos a Azure Storage Blob (sin conocer el path físico)

Tags: .net-core, fileupload, blob, azure-storage

En mi aplicación web, necesito permitirle al usuario que elija una imagen desde su máquina y la suba, y que esa imágen se almacene físicamente en mi **contenedor** de el **storage** de Azure.

La forma de hacerlo la he encontrado en muchos lugares y me funciona, pero con la **IMPORTANTE EXCEPCIÓN** de que en todos los ejemplos, suben un archivo desde su propia máquina y conociendo o harcodenado el path físico.

Pero como por cuestiones de seguridad, los input file no puede leer la dirección física del cliente, me vi obligado a utilizar la estrategia de:

1. Subo la imagen al server web a un path conocido
2. Tomo ese path, y es el que utilizo para subir a Azure Storage Blob
3. Confirmado esto, **no quiero que ese archivo se quede en el server**, solo quiero que esté en mi **contenedor**, por lo tanto, procedo a borrar el file.
4. Obtengo la siguiente excepción:

> The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Mis_carpetas\20220414.175924.683.png' because it is being used
> by another process.

Nota: probé utilizar un directorio del proyecto y también el directorio temporal del sistema operativo. Para ambos casos obtengo el mismo resultado.

Entonces, en conclusión: yo necesito subir a Azure S Blob, pero hasta donde pude averiguar, para ello necesito el path físico del archivo, por lo que necesito sí o sí subirlo a mi server y desde allí subirlo.

Quisiera que me ayuden con estas opciones:

1. Poder subirlo sin necesidad del path físico
2. Ó poder cerrar el proceso que ahora tengo, asegurando el borrado del archivo temporal en el server.
3. Alguna que ustedes propongan.

¡Muchas gracias!

_________________________ CODE ________________________

FRONT

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="conten_CargaImagenes">
                <div class="card card-success">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title" id="tituloAbmHorarios">
                            <i class="far fa-image"></i> Nueva Imagen
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="File" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                                    <label id="fileImageLabel" asp-for="File" class="custom-file-label "></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-success btn-sm pull-left" onclick="GuardarImagen()">
                                    <i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Grabar Imagen
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS Method

```
function GuardarImagen() {

    var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

    var model = new FormData(form);
    model.append('IdComercio', $('#Id').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/Comercios/GrabaFile",
        data: model,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (e) {

            if (!e.isError) {
                $("#File").val(null);
                document.getElementById("fileImageLabel").innerHTML = '';

                toastr.success(textos.imagenGrabadaOk, { timeOut: 2000 });
                InjectarNuevaImagenEnPantalla(e.data);
            } else {
                toastr.error(e.data, { timeOut: 2000 });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

BACK

```
[HttpPost]
        public ReturnData GrabaFile(UploadFileComercioDTO pData)
        {

            if (pData.File != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = UploaderFilesService.UploadToAzure(pData.File, FolderPath, pData.IdComercio.ToString());
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    do something...
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return messageError
            }
        }


public static ReturnData UploadToAzure(IFormFile pFile, string pFolder, string pIdComercio)
        {
            ReturnData returnData = new();

            if (pFile != null)
            {
                if (ValidaFile(pFile.ContentType, pFile.Length))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string nombreOriginal = pFile.FileName;
                        var nombrePartes = nombreOriginal.Split(".");
                        string extension = nombrePartes[(nombrePartes.Length - 1)];

                        string nombreFinal = GenerarTextoUnico() + "." + extension;
                        string soloNOmbre = nombreFinal; // ****

                        pFolder = Path.GetTempPath(); // *************
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(pFolder, nombreFinal);

                        using (var stream = File.Create(filePath))
                        {
                            pFile.CopyTo(stream);
                        }

                        string connectionString = "adsfasfasdfasdf";
                        string containerName = "asdfasdf";

                        nombreFinal = pIdComercio + "/" + nombreFinal;

                        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
                        var upload = container.UploadBlob(nombreFinal, File.OpenRead(filePath));

                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(filePath);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }

            return returnData;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema y la solución.

El problema era que no estaba cerrando el stream al realizar la subida.

La modificación a realizar fue en el método UploadToAzure, cambiar la siguiente línea

```
var upload = container.UploadBlob(nombreFinal, File.OpenRead(filePath));
```

por esto

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
   var upload = container.UploadBlob(nombreFinal, stream);
}
```

De esa manera al salir del **using** ya se cierra el stream y puedo proceder a borrarlo.